# $X(x)=c_1 \cosh (\gamma x) + c_2 \sinh (\gamma x)$ as a solution to $X'' - \lambda X =0, \quad \text{where} \quad \lambda>0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the ODE $$X'' - \lambda X =0, \quad where \quad  \lambda>0$$
I understand how to get a solution of the form

$$X(x)=c_1 e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x} + c_2 e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x} \quad \quad (1)$$

however I came across with the solution stated as

$$X(x)=c_1 \cosh (\gamma x) + c_2 \sinh (\gamma x)   \quad \quad (2)$$

which I don't understand. **How (1) can be transitioned into (2)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the definitions:

$$ \sinh x = \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}, \ \cosh x = \frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2} $$

and so we can see that

$$ e^x = \cosh x + \sinh x, \ e^{-x} =\cosh x - \sinh x $$

from whence we can write the solution in terms of hyperbolic sine and cosine after relabeling some of the constants.

Comment: ok, I see $\gamma=\sqrt{\lambda}$, so equivalent to the (1) would be $X(x)=(c_1+c_2)sinh (\sqrt{\lambda}x) + (c_1+c_2)cosh (\sqrt{\lambda}x) $